# Результат не выводится на веб-страницу

Tags: java, tomcat, web-apps

Задача заключается в фильтрации фамилий по принципу "те,что заканчиваются на "ий","ой","ов" выводятся на экран"

Часть кода в сервлете следующая:

```
private List<String> filterStudentNames(String[] studentNames) {
    List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String surname : studentNames) {
        if (surname.endsWith("ий") || surname.endsWith("ой") || surname.endsWith("ов")) {
            filteredList.add(surname);
        }
    }
    return filteredList;
}
```

а в файле разрешения .jsp, который, по сути, должен выводить значение на экран следующая:

```
<%
    List<String> filteredList;
    filteredList = (List<String>) request.getAttribute("filteredList");
    if (filteredList != null && !filteredList.isEmpty()) {
        for (String surname : filteredList) {
%>
<li><%= surname %></li>
<%
    }
} else {
%>
<li>No filtered names found.</li>
<%
    }
%>
```

Единственное, о чем предупреждает IntelliJ IDEA, это о строке `(List<String>) request.getAttribute("filteredList")`, обосновывая это проблемой

> Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.List<java.lang.String>'

Может поможет кто понять, что не так? В каком месте обнуляется отфильтрованный список?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А в каком месте вы вызываете метод `filterStudentNames` и где вы устанавливаете атрибут `filteredList`?

Comment: Устанавливаю атрибут в сервлете в виде request.setAttribute("filteredList", filteredList);

Метод там же с помощью 
List<String> filteredList;
            filteredList = filterStudentNames(StudentNames);